# Is there any way to overcome the limits of tsvector and tsquery in postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am using pdf of more than 80 pages, extracting the text from pdf and converting it to tsvector.
but I am getting duplicate positional valueswhen it exceeds to limit

'querytre':10668,10719,10723,16383 'quest':16383 'question':16383 'quick':4060,16383 'quilter':16383 'quit':1365,8409,12554 'quizz':16383 'quo':16383 'quot':3023,10576,10615,14531,16383 'quotat':16383 'r':12505,16383 'r-tree':12504 'rabbit':16383 'rachel':16383 'racial':16383 'rada':16383 'radic':16383 'radio':16383 'rafa':16383 'raft':7507,7611 'raghav':16383 'raini':16383 'rais':16383 'rambler':9605 'ramsha':16383 'ran':16383 'random':4436,12438,12616,16383 'rang':803,8864,16383

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?  What real-world problem is being solved by doing it that way?  Could you divide it into paragraphs and store each paragraph as a separate row?

Comment: @jjanes I am tring to perform tsquery serach for large document(GBs of data), after it will match will return the uniqueid. to speed up the search i am converting the text (extracted from document) to tsvector and have index. If i divide into paragraphs table will have multiple rows right, is there any threshold for dividing deocument into paragraph so that positional value doesn't exceeds the limit, since position values plays very important role for proximity(followed by) search?

Comment: It sounds like you only have one document?  How is an index with the whole thing as one row going to speed that up?  I think you are just using the wrong tool here.  There are dedicated tools for document processing.  You should probably use them to recognize paragraph boundaries, as well as to do the rest of whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: No there will be multiple documents, I need to return the document id whenever tsquery matches  the document

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?